# Как зашифровать /boot раздел при установке?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, шифрование

Устанавливаю Ubuntu 22.04, Legacy/MBR Boot (это важно). Хочу зашифровать системный раздел (даже /boot!). Если вообще делать отдельный раздел /boot, то он также должен быть либо зашифрован, либо в readonly файловой системе - т е squashfs, EROFS, либо же ext(2/3/4) с EXT4_DEDUP_BLOCK (кто знает про раздел super в последних Android-ах, тот поймет, о чем я). Гайдов в интернете немного, тем более конкретно по Ubuntu, а что ещё хуже, там не шифруется /boot, что чисто с точки зрения безопасности весьма плохо. Сунул туда rootkit и подменил опции в grub.cfg - и система скомпрометирована. Шифрование использую как альтернативу Secure Boot, который есть только в UEFI (да ещё и проблемный из-за ключей Microsoft-а, если верить статьям с Хабра об UEFI).

Comment: Это невозможно по банальной логике: чтобы запустить зашифрованную программу (загрузчик), её кто-то как-то должен сперва расшифровать, а кто и как?

Comment: Не обязательно именно шифровать /boot раздел.  Достаточно отформатировать его в read-only FS вроде EROFS, squashfs или хотя бы ext4 с флагом EXT4_DEDUP_BLOCKS. Смысл шифрования /boot не в шифровании как таковом, а в защите от перезаписи. А вот корень - да, зашифровать к чертям.

Comment: Если у злоумышленника будет доступ к системе, ему абсолютно ничего не помешает записать свой собственный EROFS или squashfs. Если у злоумышленника не будет доступа к системе, то всё это не имеет смысла. В общем, в обоих случаях это не имеет смысла

Comment: имеет смысл научиться делать secureboot на uefi или носить бут раздел с собой на флешке)

Comment: eri, система - Legacy BIOS/MBR, какой к черту UEFI?

Comment: andreymal, это уже другой вопрос, да и на такой случай можно считывать (в случае подозрений) хэш раздела ручками, если заподозрили неладное. Я ещё люблю отключать `quiet splash` в cmdline, ибо мне как тру-линуксовику лучше видеть логи, чем бутлого.

Comment: @RandomDice779 хэши можно и на обычном ext4 посчитать

Comment: Ну... Зачем столь открытую дорожку делать с красным ковриком? Понятно, что можно через dd сдампить /boot, затем делаем `unmksquashfs` или просто копируем файлы из раздела, но даже в таком случае придётся постараться. одно дело, когда тебе достаточно смонтировать ext раздел и все, совсем другое работать с пермаментно read-only разделом. Особенно круто будет с EROFS или EXT4 с dedup_blocks (привет super.img из Android) т к это физический раздел на диске, а не squashfs (по сути img) образ.

Comment: Плюс если хоть как-то будет скомпрометирована система - это либо отобразится в логах dmesg (я отрубаю бутанимацию) либо будет изменен cmdline. Крайний вариант - в случае малейших подозрений грузимся со сторонней системы с USB, считаем хэши boot раздела и всего на нём, бэкап прячем за семью печатями, там же держим хэши для сверки! Или вообще подписи из OpenSSL/GNUPG.

Comment: запишите раздел `/boot` на флешку, нажмите кнопочку read-only и носите под сердцем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/boot надо шифровать через LUKS1:

```
root@live:/ # cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks1 /dev/boot-partition
```

Тогда GRUB2 сможет его расшифровать и спросить у вас пароль.

Comment: А кто будет расшифровывать сам GRUB2? А если GRUB2 останется незашифрованным - то какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Что вы сделаете с ассемблерным кодом в <2Кбайта? (Именно для внедрения бэкдора или перехвата пароля)

Comment: Подменю его на другой ассемблерный код, который загрузит мой код, который спросит у пользователя пароль и с помощью него начнёт пакостить

Comment: Ну и насчёт «<2Кбайта» — GRUB2 обычно устанавливает себя между MBR и первым разделом диска, а разделы обычно выравниваются по мегабайтам, так что при стандартной установке системы у злоумышленника есть целых 1023 килобайта, в которые можно напихать кучу вредоносного кода. Придётся повозиться с разметкой, чтобы и для GRUB2 места хватило, и злоумышленнику было некуда впихнуть вредоносный код (и всё равно я думаю, что по-настоящему хорошему злоумышленнику и пары килобайт тоже хватит)

Comment: Этот вопрос следует закрыть как попытку бессмысленного троллинга,

Comment: Нет, передо мной серьёзно стоял такой вопрос, и я даже сейчас принял свой же ответ